# HttpClient PCL not working properly on windows phone

Tags: asynchronous, windows-phone, httpclient, portable-class-library

```
var json = await http.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

this works on both windows store, windows phone and windows form app, however the following code only works on windows store and windows form app, not on windows phone. The getAsync never returns. Does anyone know the reason? Is there a bug in the implementation of the PCL for windows phone?

```
var response = http.GetAsync(uri).Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: It could be a deadlock. I don't understand, why aren't you awaiting the result of `http.GetAsync(uri)`?

Comment: Well, I want to ensure that I get SuccessStatusCode, i don't get why the same code work for windows store, and windows form app, for not windows phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not block on `async` code; there is the [possibility of a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I describe on my blog.

Comment: Stephen's correct, you're hitting a deadlock. The Phone networking stack attempts back onto the UI thread when the response has returned, but can't because it's blocked waiting on the Result.